# Xcode 10 - interface builder document

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode10

I'm unable to change the Interface Builder Document version to Xcode 10.0 for my existing storyboards. It always revert back to Xcode 9.0 after selecting Xcode 10.0, Save and Close when prompt, and re-opening my storyboards.  Even when creating new storyboards it defaults to Xcode 9.0

[image]
[image]

Is there a way to make Xcode 10.0 my default?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Seeing the same thing as you are even when setting the Project Document: Project Format to Xcode 10.0 compatible.

Comment: Any answer on this? My storyboards also default to Xcode 9.0. Seems like IB Xcode 9.0 is the latest and IB Xcode 10 is still in beta?

Comment: Looks like this issue is fixed in Xcode 10.2

Comment: I have the same problem with Xcode 11.3. It says "opens in... latest Xcode 10", while I would expect to have Xcode 11 as latests. Where can I change the default?