# UI Not Updating During Reset for Simple Swift 4.2 Game

Tags: ios, user-interface, xcode10, swift4.2

I'm new to iOS and Swift development, and I'm looking for help with a practice application.

It's a super simple game where you move a slider to "guess" a target/random number, and you are either correct or incorrect. The game itself runs and play works, but I ran into issues when I tried to add a "Play Again" button to reset the UI for a new game.

The issue I'm seeing is when I click the "Play Again?" button, the UI does not update. I'm trying to hide labels and change messages, but the UI does not change like it does when the game plays.

Does anyone know what mistake I'm making that's resulting in not having a UI update when I click "Play Again?" (linked to the reset() function). For reference, I'm using Xcode 10.0 and Swift 4.2.

Thanks!

**Pictures of Boring Game**

[image]

[image]

[image]

**ViewController**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var targetNumber = 0
    @IBOutlet weak var message: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var slider: UISlider!
    @IBOutlet weak var resultLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var playAgainBtn: UIButton!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        playAgainBtn.isHidden = true
        
        targetNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(101))
        message.text = "Move slider to: \(targetNumber)"
    }
    
    func correct() {
        resultLabel.text = "Bullseye!"
        resultLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    }
    
    func wrong() {
        resultLabel.text = "Whoops! Not very good at this, are you?"
        resultLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    }

    func scoreInRange() -> Bool {
        let allowed_error = 3
        
        return Int(slider.value) >= Int(targetNumber) - allowed_error && Int(slider.value) <= Int(targetNumber) + allowed_error
    }
    
    @IBAction func reset(_ sender: Any) {
        slider.setValue(50.0, animated: false)
        
        targetNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(101))
        message.text = "Move slider to: \(targetNumber)"
        
        resultLabel.isHidden = true
        playAgainBtn.isHidden = true
    }
    
    @IBAction func score(_ sender: Any) {
        
        if scoreInRange() {
            correct()
        } else {
            wrong()
        }
        
        playAgainBtn.isHidden = false
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Are you *sure* the `@IBAction` is connected? Add a `print("tapped')` statement and see if it shows up in debug console.

Comment: @DonMag Yeah. I tried printing and the values themselves seem correct. slider.value updates to 50.0 and a new random targetNumber both print to the console.

Comment: Hmmm.. I just gave your code a try. Works fine for me... Xcode 10.3 Swift 4.2

Comment: Interesting. After I saw your comment I did more digging, and I think the issue is my Mac and XCode installation. My XCode 10.0 is reverting to XCode 9 for interface building, and if I wait a long time I see the UI updates working better. According to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52434684/xcode-10-interface-builder-document I should upgrade my XCode to at least 10.2 and it should build the interface correctly. 
Thank you so much for your help, @DonMag !